# Questions about Time-series neural network tool (ntstool) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series

I have to use NAR network to train a time-series for my project. To have an idea of how time-series tool (ntstool) works in **MATLAB** , I used the GUI of **ntstool** in matlab  with an example dataset of **chickenpoxTargets** containing `498` timesteps of one element. While training I used a neural network with `10` hidden layers and `delay value = 5`.  The GUI generated the following code :

```
% Solve an Autoregression Time-Series Problem with a NAR Neural Network
% Script generated by NTSTOOL
% Created Mon May 12 10:47:14 IST 2014
%
% This script assumes this variable is defined:
%
%   chickenpoxTargets - feedback time series.

targetSeries = chickenpoxTargets;

% Create a Nonlinear Autoregressive Network
feedbackDelays = 1:5;
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = narnet(feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize);

% Prepare the Data for Training and Simulation
% The function PREPARETS prepares timeseries data for a particular network,
% shifting time by the minimum amount to fill input states and layer states.
% Using PREPARETS allows you to keep your original time series data unchanged, while
% easily customizing it for networks with differing numbers of delays, with
% open loop or closed loop feedback modes.
[inputs,inputStates,layerStates,targets] = preparets(net,{},{},targetSeries);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets,inputStates,layerStates);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs,inputStates,layerStates);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotresponse(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrcorr(errors)
%figure, plotinerrcorr(inputs,errors)

% Closed Loop Network
% Use this network to do multi-step prediction.
% The function CLOSELOOP replaces the feedback input with a direct
% connection from the outout layer.
netc = closeloop(net);
[xc,xic,aic,tc] = preparets(netc,{},{},targetSeries);
yc = netc(xc,xic,aic);
perfc = perform(net,tc,yc)

% Early Prediction Network
% For some applications it helps to get the prediction a timestep early.
% The original network returns predicted y(t+1) at the same time it is given y(t+1).
% For some applications such as decision making, it would help to have predicted
% y(t+1) once y(t) is available, but before the actual y(t+1) occurs.
% The network can be made to return its output a timestep early by removing one delay
% so that its minimal tap delay is now 0 instead of 1.  The new network returns the
% same outputs as the original network, but outputs are shifted left one timestep.
nets = removedelay(net);
[xs,xis,ais,ts] = preparets(nets,{},{},targetSeries);
ys = nets(xs,xis,ais);
closedLoopPerformance = perform(net,tc,yc)
```

Now I have following **Three** questions :

1. What does the **delay value (d) ** in the GUI means. Does it mean that while training the network assumes that each timestep value is dependent on last 'd' timesteps' values ?
2. What is the syntax to predict the values at future timesteps ?
3. When I simulate the network using `sim(results.net,input)` where results.net is the neural network and input is the input row vector to predict the output , I get the same output no matter what is the input row vector. More specifically the following is output for different input vectors:

   ```
   sim(results.net,[956])

   ans =

     136.8790

   sim(results.net,[957])

   ans =

     136.8790

   sim(results.net,[954,966])

   ans =

     136.8790  136.8790
   ```

Why I am getting the same output?

Answer (score 0):

1. The delay parameter represents the timesteps back you insert into your model

   `y(t) = f(y(t-1), y(t-2), ... y(t-d))`

   Therefore each timestep depends on the last `d` timesteps
2. For predicting further timesteps without inserting new data you have to change you model into a `closedloop` model.

   Means as it is show in your script:

   ```
   % convert from openloop to closedloop
   netc = closeloop(net);
   % prepare your data for the network (scaling!!)
   [xc,xic,aic,tc] = preparets(netc,{},{},targetSeries);
   % calculate new output
   yc = netc(xc,xic,aic);
   % get performance of network
   perfc = perform(net,tc,yc)
   ```
3. You have to prepare your input data before using net (with **preparets**). As it is shown in the [MATLAB Documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/sim.html) `sim()` needs several parameters:

   ```
   [Y,Xf,Af] = sim(net,X,Xi,Ai,T)
   ```

   Also:

   > ... sim function is called implicitly by calling the neural network object (net) as a function.

   Means: You can use `net()`, as shown in 2., the same way as `sim()`

   Without scaling your input is not the same as the net learned from. Therefore it outputs wrong numbers.